# Is it possible to add (stash) several file types in git?

Tags: git, syntax, git-stash, git-add

Assume I have

```
git status
...
Changes not staged for commit:
        modified:   A.R
        modified:   B.Rmd
        modified:   C.txt
...
```

Is there a way to do the following:

```
git add *.Rmd OR *.R
```

or

```
git stash *.Rmd OR *.R
```

? I can't find it in the docs for [add](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) or [stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git add "*.R"
```

works fine (with quotes). In the doc, it's mentioned as the [`<pathspec>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt-ltpathspecgt82308203) you can give as a parameter.

For stash, you'll have to explicitly use the (usually implied) `push` :

```
git stash push "*.R"
```

The doc mentions :

> When pathspec is given to git stash push, the new stash entry records the modified states only for the files that match the pathspec.

*(Edit after comments)* And if you need both types, just give multiple pathspecs like this :

```
git add "*.R" "*.Rmd"
git stash push "*.R" "*.Rmd"
```

Comment: But can you do it in one line instead of `git add *.Rmd` followed by `git add *.R`?

Comment: So simple! Sometimes useful things are really hidden in git ;-)